# Split Screen Network Link Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

One issue I had with the first Borderlands game was that multi-player seemed to require a console/game each if you wanted to play with more than 2 players.

Looking at the UI of Borderlands 2 it looks like you can play with more than 2 players while on a console. Is it possible to play with 4 Players with just two consoles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I play split-screen at my house (2 players on one console) and am joined by two friends playing split-screen at that house (again, 2 players on one console).

This is on the Playstation network but I personally heard Gearbox reps say that they made this work on all console platforms.

Comment: Awesome! I've bought a 2nd copy of the game will rock the hell out of this.

Comment: See my edit above. They said they made this work on Console platforms. I don't think split-screen works on PC via Steam.

Comment: I'm on the X-Box but it's good to know either way.